# Will List<T> Shrink In Size If You Remove Elements

Tags: c#, list

When a `List<T>` gets full, it doubles in size, occupying twice the memory, but would it automatically decrease in size if you removed elements from it?

As much as I understand decreasing the `Capacity` would not mean relocating all the data in memory, it would just need to drop off the end of the reserved memory, but does it actually do it?

Comment: There is no way to "shrink" the array w/o actually allocating a new smaller array and copying the current content.

Comment: Does it really *double* in size? AFAIK in order for the amortized operations to be efficient it is sufficient that the saze is increased by  a constant multiplicative factor (e.g. `new_size = size * 1.3`) and I believe in most implementations a factor of about `1.5` is used to avoid wasting too much memory.

Comment: @Bakuriu [.Net `List<T>` doubles](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,eb66b6616c6fd4ef), [OpenJDK `ArrayList<T>` grows by 50%](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l237), MSVC++14 `std::vector` grows by 50% ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector" line 1584: `_Grow_to`).

Comment: @Johnbot I was just curious. AFAIK python collections typically grow by about 50% too.

Comment: @Bakuriu you got me curios enough to look up the sources I knew :) The [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f24143b25e4f83368ff6182bebe14f885073015c/Objects/listobject.c#L42) is 12.5% + `requested size < 9 ? 3 : 6`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, `List` doesn't ever decrease the capacity unless you explicitly lower it yourself by setting that property or using `TrimExcess`, except when you call `Clear` and it can remove the buffer entirely.

Of course, that's just the current implementation, and it is an implementation detail, so you cannot *rely* on it not shrinking the backing array.

Comment: You are asserting there is no documented guarantee about `List<T>`'s behavior in the shrinking case?

Comment: @Yakk If you *explicitly* remove the capacity with, say `TrimExcess`, then that's behavior as per specs.  How it adjusts the capacity when adding/removing items isn't specified, and so whatever the current behavior is is subject to change.

Comment: so `List<T>` that reallocates linearly (and hence takes O(n^2) time) when you append is compliant with the documented guaratees?  That is *horrible*.  "If Count is less than Capacity, this method is an O(1) operation. If the capacity needs to be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count." -- yep.  Horrible.

Comment: @Yakk It would be pretty unlikely that that would ever happen, but yes, the type doesn't *guarantee* that it allocates memory along an exponential curve.

Answer (score 9):

From the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,2765070d40f47b98), we can see that the `Remove` method calls the `RemoveAt` method, which is implemented like this:

```
public void RemoveAt(int index) {
    if ((uint)index >= (uint)_size) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    _size--;
    if (index < _size) {
        Array.Copy(_items, index + 1, _items, index, _size - index);
    }
    _items[_size] = default(T);
    _version++;
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any resizing of the underlying array `_items`. It only sets the item at the index to the default value.

Basically, no.

Also note that the `Clear` method does not resize the array either. It calls `Array.Clear` to set all items in the underlying array to the default values.

```
public void Clear() {
    if (_size > 0)
    {
        Array.Clear(_items, 0, _size); // Don't need to doc this but we clear the elements so that the gc can reclaim the references.
        _size = 0;
    }
    _version++;
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, `Array.Clear` doesn't change the length of `_items` array. So, even after a call to `Clear` capacity stays the same.

Comment: @defaultlocale Exactly! That's why I said it only frees the memory. The reference source also shows this fact

Comment: In this sense `Remove` also frees the memory for a single removed element. I just didn't understand what's the implied difference

Comment: @defaultlocale Oh I get your point now. Thanks for the reminder! I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 8):

No, `List<T>` will **not** automatically reclaim any of that space as currently implemented, and it's unlikely this implementation will change any time soon.

But that's only part of the story. Remember that, generally speaking, `List<T>` only stores **references** to your items. If you have a large list with many objects, and you remove half of them such that nothing uses the removed objects any more, something very close to half the memory you attribute to your list  **will** be reclaimed when the GC collects those objects.

Additionally, my understanding is the current implementation will *compact* the remaining items, such that as the list grows again it's re-using spots in memory allocated for the current array used by the list internally.

Finally, there are ways to manually reclaim the space... but use them sparingly. Most of the time, the GC knows best. Calling `TrimExcess()` because you just removed a handful of items from a large list is usually a net loss to your application.

Comment: That assumes you're storing reference types in the `List`, but if you are, this applies.

Comment: A very interesting remark about reference types, thank you :)

Comment: @Servy hence the "generally speaking" hedge, and the careful use of "objects" vs "items"

Comment: "the current implementation will compact the remaining items" - I'm not sure there is any "compacting" done, other than what is required by the semantics of an indexed list, anyway.

Comment: I think the compacting refers to the fact that the GC will move objects around to avoid fragmentation. This is quite different from the List’s capacity being reduced during GC by it automatically calling `TrimExcess()` for you. If such a thing ever happened, GC would have an unexpected and observable side effect which I’ve never seen people talk about nor seen in [the](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.1) [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity?view=netframework-4.7.1).